# Chrome suddenly disabled "IDM extension"?

Tags: google-chrome, internet, download, download-manager

I didn't have this problem till now, but today suddenly chrome disabled my "IDM extension" so i searched a lot, but the results i found were out-of-date (<2015) so is this problem solved or still i can't install extension out of the chrome store? this happened to me before, and i had to reinstall my windows and i got my idm extension back after reinstalling windows but is there anyway that i could enable it without reinstalling my windows?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a big change in chrome from Google. Google has made changes in it's policy regarding chrome that it will not allow extension install from outside the chrome web store.

It is done to protect users from malware and scam on the web.

There is no way out for this.  Sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, which worked for me:

Remove the IDM extension currently installed in your Chrome
then go to this site [IDM Integration Module
offered by www.internetdownloadmanager.com](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/idm-integration-module/ngpampappnmepgilojfohadhhmbhlaek/related) and add the extension there, this way Chrome will not auto disable the extension anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Add IDM to Google Chrome using the IDMCC or crx file.

this problem will never come again.

Comment: Explaining how to do this will make this an answer. Also an earlier answer already suggests using a manual install method. Avoid posting as answers things that have already been said unless you have substantial new or currently missing information to add.